# Why this error: removeNode only works on internal nodes at present

Tags: xml, r

I am writing a fairly simple R script that will generate some XML. I am using the XML package and doing something like this:

```
doc <- newXMLDoc()
root = newXMLNode("Root", namespaceDefinitions=c("xsi"="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"), doc=doc)
newXMLNode("Foo", sample(g_IDS, 1), parent=root) #g_IDS is a vector with some random guids
```

And then a lot of:

```
bar = newXMLNode("bar", parent = root)
```

More nodes are added and bar gets some child nodes as well. There are a lot of calls to `newXMLNode` and I am not *removing* any nodes (at least not knowingly).

At the end I write everything to a file like this:

```
cat(saveXML(doc, file = "out.xml"))
```

This works, but I get 50 warnings that say:

In removeNodes.list(kids) : removeNode only works on internal nodes at present

and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently running into this situation, the fix came with properly subscripting any *named* elements of list. Possibly `g_IDS` maintains names to its elements, so consider taking first element of the returned `sample()`: `newXMLNode("Foo", sample(g_IDS, 1)[[1]], parent=root)`

To demonstrate:

```
g_IDs <- setNames(as.list(seq(1,50,1)), paste0("ID", seq(1,50,1)))
# $ID1
# [1] 1

# $ID2
# [1] 2

# $ID3
# [1] 3
...

doc <- newXMLDoc()
root = newXMLNode("Root", 
                  namespaceDefinitions=c("xsi"="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"), 
                  doc=doc)
newXMLNode("Foo", sample(g_IDs, 1), parent=root)
# <Foo>1</Foo> 
# Warning message:
# In removeNodes.list(kids) :
#  removeNode only works on internal nodes at present

doc <- newXMLDoc()
root = newXMLNode("Root", 
                  namespaceDefinitions=c("xsi"="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"), 
                  doc=doc)
newXMLNode("Foo", sample(g_IDs, 1)[[1]], parent=root)
# <Foo>4</Foo>
```

Comment: @Pixelkracht - Awesome, this helped! Usually opened questions over 6 months old, you expect newcomer OPs to disappear forever!